# How can i fill a list or array when checking in condition?

Tags: c#, .net, arraylist

begginer here :). So i want to fill an array or list with results from a foreach loop.

Noob example

```
foreach (var drive in mounted_drives)
        {
            //asigning new path where to look for the UNCpath

            string getUNC = path + "\\" + drive;
            reg2 = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(getUNC);
            string UNCPath = reg2.GetValue("RemotePath").ToString(); //getting UNC PATH
            Console.WriteLine(UNCPath);
        }
```

so here i want each UNCPath to be saved to outside array or list that i can use later to write it in a file.

Dont wanna spill here my ideas since im not that deep into C# and .NET yet..

It may be simple but im stuck -.-

Thanks in advance

Comment: `var uncPaths = mounted_drives.Select(drive => $"{path}\\{drive}").Select(Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey).Select(reg => reg.GetValue("RemotePath").ToString()).ToList();`. Did not check this for typos. But this should create a new list containing the results of your steps.

Comment: @Knoop Select is something new to me and i will need some time or examples on how and when to use it. Still thanks, nice to see how everyone has a different approach to problem.

Comment: Well I would definately advise you to take a look at it sometime (and `LINQ`in general). Basically it's a framework that provides functionality for `IEnumerables` (things you loop over). `Select` transforms every element into something new. So for example I have a list of 5 ints: (`var intList = new List<int> { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };` I can use `Select` to transform all the elements: `var newList = intList.Select(i => i * i).ToList();. `newList` will be a new list (this is done by the `ToList()`call at the end), containing the numbers: `{ 0, 1, 4, 9, 16}`.

Comment: And since what you want is basically 3 transformation steps after each other on every element in a list that's what I created by chaining the 3 `Select` statements (every `Select` takes the result of the previous `Select`) and this is repeated for every element and then all those new transformed values are added to a new list by the `ToList()` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
List<string> mylist = new List<string>();

foreach (var drive in mounted_drives)
{
    string getUNC = path + "\\" + drive;
    reg2 = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(getUNC);
    string UNCPath = reg2.GetValue("RemotePath").ToString(); //getting UNC PATH
    mylist.Add(UNCPath);
}
```

In case you should need to have an array instead of a list, you can use the method ToArray();

```
string[] myarray = mylist.ToArray();
```

Comment: Good answer. Be sure to declare the "myList" variable outside of the foreach loop (like it is in this answer) or it will not be available after the loop completes.

Comment: Thanks man ! I was not sure on how to approach this with a List. I was sure that this needs to be outside of the loop since it would dispose of all after it is finished with loop

Answer (score 1):

> So i want to fill an array or list with results from a foreach loop. I want each UNCPath to be saved to outside array or list that I can use later.

There are other answer that address this already, but I have a different approach to this and a few suggestions to improve your current code.

The first suggestion is don't concatenate strings like you are:

```
 string getUNC = path + "\\" + drive;
```

Look into the [Path.Combine Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=net-5.0) to do this for you.

Secondly you should always release resources when you can. You are opening up registry keys which means we should also always [close](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.close?view=net-5.0) and [dispose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.dispose?view=net-5.0) of them.

Below is a static class with an extension routine. The routine returns an `IEnumerable<string>`, this way it can defer execution until you actually need it. This is helpful considering you mentioned you want to use it later as a `List<string>` and or `Array`.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Win32;

public static class RegistryHelper
{
        public static IEnumerable<string> GetRemotePaths(this IEnumerable<string> drives, string path)
        {
            if (drives == null || drives.Count() == 0 || string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
                yield break;

            foreach (string drive in drives)
            {
                using (RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(Path.Combine(path, drive)))
                {
                    if (key != null && key.GetValue("RemotePath") != null)
                    {
                        yield return key.GetValue("RemotePath").ToString();
                        key.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Here's an example of usage for this extension routine:

```
 var ienum = mounted_drives.GetRemotePaths(YOURPATHHERE); // Make sure to put your path in - delayed execution until you actually need it
 var lstPaths = mounted_drives.GetRemotePaths(YOURPATHHERE).ToList(); // Make sure to put your path in - converts the return to a `List<string>`
 var arrPaths = mounted_drives.GetRemotePaths(YOURPATHHERE).ToArray(); // Make sure to put your path in - converts the return to an array of strings
```

Comment: Thanks very much. .net i really wast for a beginner like myself and im using the "brute force".

Comment: I have tested both answers and they work, made few adjustment and ill use the Path.Combine Method in the future :D

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a List outside the foreach and then appending what you want inside it.

```
var list = new List<string>();
list.Add("my string");
```

You can also use the Select method:

```
var list = mounted_drives.Select(e => {
    string getUNC = path + "\\" + drive;
    reg2 = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(getUNC);
    string UNCPath = reg2.GetValue("RemotePath").ToString(); //getting UNC PATH
    return UNCPath;
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the approach !  

@Codexer made more clear on how to approach. Thanks Guys